# Path forward into making Python web applications

Tags: python, web-applications

I currently know a working knowledge of Python and some related libraries (including the included-with-Python SQLite) for the purpose of making **desktop** applications.

I would now like to start to make **"web applications"**.  By this, I mean that whatever is on the desktop application will be done by visiting a website...so the web page will have all the same sorts of widgets found in desktop apps (buttons, pulldowns, textboxes, etc).

I am **not** interested in making just static web sites or online magazines or things like that.

All I know about anything web-related is the basics of HTML and CSS.  I also get the sense that I will have to learn Javascript and find a Javascript widget toolkit for the widgets.  **I'm unclear on what else I will need.**  I've heard a lot of good things about the Django web framework, but I'm not sure what the role of a "web framework" is in the mix here (and I got the sense that Django was used mostly to build things like online magazines, not web applications), though I get the sense I will need one to handle the basics of routing information through the web.

I'm also open to the idea of using a different programming language than Python, though I like it and would prefer to keep using it.  *I'd like to start simple and make small toy apps just to get the basic ideas, and then build from there.*

**EDIT FOR SPECIFIC QUESTION:  What are the minimum tools/services will I need to get/learn to produce web apps (as defined above) using Python?**

**EDIT 2:**  I'm removing references to SaaS.  Let's just call it a widget-using web app.

Comment: There really isn't a solid question here.  Can you edit this question to ask something more specific?

Comment: @maple_shaft I hope that helps.

Comment: Why do you need to use Python? What you are describing is a web application, not SAAS. Any of the web programming languages can be used for this: PHP, ASP, JSP, ColdFusion, etc.

Comment: @CFL_Jeff This might be part of my problem:  what is the difference between a web application and SAAS?

Comment: @CFL_Jeff I don't need to use Python; I'd just like to, since I already know it and like it.

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon the following two things:

> ...I've heard a lot of good things about the Django web framework...
>
> ...though I get the sense I will need one to handle the basics of routing
>   information through the web...

I'd suggest that you go for a python microframework. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) would be a good choice. Do not go for Django if you need a subset of its features and a microframework is giving you those features.

And regarding services/tools, you may need to use atleast these for your app if you want to do on your web app whatever a user can do on a desktop:

- Templating engine (e.g. Jinja)
- SQL/NoSQL Database (e.g. PostgreSQL)
- Form validation package (e.g. WTForms)
- Caching (e.g. memcached or redis)
- (Stellar) Javascript for sure, HTML5 + CSS3 or jQuery to make your work easier

Comment: Thanks--this is just the sort of stuff I wouldn't be able to as easily find without querying a human.  And what about a (Javascript, I guess?) widget toolkit?

Comment: Although I haven't used a JS widget toolkit myself, I'm aware of Dojo and Qooxdoo... You may give them a shot...